# Why does OpenNLP's Document Categorizer train so fast?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

OpenNLP is significantly underperforming other document classifiers I've tested, so before I give up on it, I decided to make sure I'm playing around will all the dials and knobs. One thing that stood out for me was OpenNLP is training my model extremely fast (around 1.2 seconds). Other NLP tools I've used can take minutes, if not hours to train. I have around 12k records in my training file.

I've tried to increase the iterations from 10 to 10000, unfortunately, it does not seem to have any impact on the training time or accuracy.

The odd thing is OpenNLP's docs state the following regarding the training duration: "Now might be a good time to cruise over to Hulu or something, because this could take a while if you've got a large training set". This makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong.

```java
            int TRAINING_ITERATIONS = 10000;

            InputStreamFactory dataIn = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(new File(dataSetFileName));
            ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
            ObjectStream<DocumentSample> sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);

            // define the training parameters
            TrainingParameters params = new TrainingParameters();
            params.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, TRAINING_ITERATIONS+"");
            params.put(TrainingParameters.CUTOFF_PARAM, 0+"");
            params.put(AbstractTrainer.ALGORITHM_PARAM, NaiveBayesTrainer.NAIVE_BAYES_VALUE);

            FeatureGenerator[] featureGenerators = { new NGramFeatureGenerator(1,1),
                    new NGramFeatureGenerator(2,3) };
            DoccatFactory factory = new DoccatFactory(featureGenerators);


            // create a model from training data
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

            // Start the watch, do some task and stop the watch.
            stopWatch.start();


            model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", sampleStream, params, factory);
            stopWatch.stop();
            System.out.println("Training Time: " + stopWatch.getTime()+"ms"); // finishes in 1.2 second!!!
```

Here is the output I'm getting

```
Indexing events with TwoPass using cutoff of 0

    Computing event counts...  done. 2407 events
    Indexing...  done.
Collecting events... Done indexing in 0.84 s.
Incorporating indexed data for training...  
done.
    Number of Event Tokens: 2407
        Number of Outcomes: 12
      Number of Predicates: 44219
Computing model parameters...
Stats: (455/2407) 0.18903199002908183
...done.
Training Time: 1241ms
```

Does the iterations parameter even do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out, Naive Bayes is just a very fast algorithm because it does not have an optimization step. The iterations parameter don't really do much. If you use any of the other training algorithms which are included, it does take forever to train. Surprisingly, for my dataset the other algorithms also result in much worse accuracy even though I trained it for hours.